# which command add the total in command ls|xargs wc -l?

Tags: shell, xargs

ls just prints out the files in directory, and wc -l counts the line num for specific filename, xargs will send the ls output one by one to `wc -l`, but the final result comes with total, why?

sample output:

```
  14 doc.txt
 230 legion.c
 519 legion_agent.c
  70 legion_manager.c
  52 legion_privilege.c
 236 logic_agent.c
 349 protocol.c
1470 total
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`wc` combines the total lines of all files that were passed to is as arguments. `xargs` collects lines from input and puts them all at once as one set of multiple arguments to `wc` so you get the total of all those files.

As an example if I have files `a` and `b`, and I run:

```
wc -l a b
```

I would get

```
 28 a
 17 b
 45 total
```

Similarly if imitate the output of `ls` with `(echo a; echo b;)` added with `xargs` we'd get the same output:

```
(echo a; echo b;) | xargs wc -l
```

Output:

```
 28 a
 17 b
 45 total
```

If we add echo:

```
(echo a; echo b;) | xargs echo wc -l
```

Output:

```
wc -l a b
```

Comment: `xargs` also splits the list of file name arguments if it exceeds `ARG_MAX`, in which case you will get multiple `wc` invocations and thus multiple (sub-) `total` lines.

Comment: thanks @konsolebox, I misunderstood the working mode of xargs. I thought xargs trigger `wc -l` on each line output of ls. And `wc -l` didn't put up total line when there was only one argument supply.

Answer (score 0):

try this line, see if it gave you what you want:

```
grep -c '.*' *.*
```